# How to transform Web.config with TFS 2013 continous integration and copy to output directory

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, web.config-transform

I'm using TFS 2013 to build many solutions; each with different solution configurations.  I'm also transforming web.config based on the build definition process setting.  If the build definition is configured to deploy the web project, web.config is properly being transformed - everything is good there.

However, the web.config that is copied to the build output directory is NOT being transformed.  I realize this may be as designed.

So, my question is:

Is it possible for the web.config that is copied to the output directory as part of a TFS continuous integration build definition to be transformed the same as if it were deployed?

I'm not too interested in SlowCheetah as the developer has announced he's stopping work / support on the project.  https://github.com/sayedihashimi/slow-cheetah/issues/158

I'm also sure I can come up with a custom post build script to do this as a last resort.  But for now, I'm curious if anyone has been successful at getting a transformed web.config copied to the output directory of a TFS build definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, you have only two options to apply transforms: SlowCheetah (based on Visual Studio APIs) or publish the site. Unless you use a different "transformation" language, your only choice is to write your own tool.

If you want you can use a different language and tools. As an example, I have been very successful with [XML Preprocess](https://xmlpreprocess.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you drop all of the configs to your build drop and do the transform at deployment time. That way you don't have to rebuild to deploy the same version. If you use Release Management for Visual Studio for deployment you can have two conversions. The base one as dev.config that you use at debug time and the deployed one that matches the configuration that you build that has the RM variables ready to replace depending on the environment.